# Do i have to identify purge acl in varnish config?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have just read Thijs Feryn's excellent book about Varnish where he states that

> "if you don’t protect access to your purge logic via an ACL, you can
>   end up in major trouble. Any other script kiddie could scan your site
>   map and execute PURGE calls on every URL on your site."

However this is not the case in my case. I got `405 forbidden` response when I try to purge the cache from local machine and I wasn't even able to connect to port 6082 of the server from another computer.

Only the WordPress press with secret varnish key can purge the cache. So do I still have to create an ACL and make a rule which lets the ACL IP's purge the cache? I'm using varnish 5.0 on Debian 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to still implement some extra VCL logic to protect your content when purging.
It's not mandatory, but two factors instead of a single one is better.